# Adding Vnet to Azure SQLDB

Tags: azure

I heard about the new update on Azure SQLDB that it can be connected to vnet but can't find any blogs on this new information.

Can someone throw some light on this information?

Comment: i think its still in private preview, i might be wrong though

Comment: @The User Currently, it is possible. I add it as an answer. Hope it help more people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, it is supported. Please refer to this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/roadmap/vnet-service-endpoints-in-azure-sql-database/).

> Azure SQL Database will allow you to set firewall rules for specific
>   public IPs, and will give you the option of allowing all Azure
>   Services’ IPs to connect to your Servers. If you're looking for finer
>   grained connectivity limitations, you would have to provision a Static
>   Public IP, which can be hard to manage and costly when done at scale.
>   Virtual Network service endpoints will allow you to limit connectivity
>   to your Azure SQL Database Servers from given subnets within a Virtual
>   Network.

You could do it on Azure Portal. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview).